# How does recursive function return its value?

Tags: c++, c, recursion

I'm trying to understand "Recursion" topic and i cant get how this  recursive function return its argument after it leaves "if" provision.

```
int sum(int x);
int main(){
    int num;
    printf("Enter a num : ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    int result=sum(num);
    printf("Result : %d\n",result);
    return 0;
}
sum(int x){
    if (x > 4){
        return sum(x-1);
    }
}
```

For example, if i edit my "sum" function as "if (x>2)" it will return 2 value. Thats what im wondering. Sum(2) doesnt have any value but it returns 2. 
Thanks!

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: `sum(int x){` isn't valid c++ code at all.

Comment: Your `sum` function is broken. It needs to return something in *all* cases. Your program has Undefined Behaviour. Remember: just because it compiles does *not* mean it is correct.

Comment: Sorry guys i wrote it in C , i thought it works also for C++. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> sum(int x){
>     if (x > 4){
>         return sum(x-1);
>     }
> }
> ```

does not return a value because a return is missing in the *else* branch and only that missing *else* branch finishes the recursion

> i cant get how this recursive function return its argument after it leaves "if" provision.

Because of the missing return the **behavior is undefined**, if I do on my computer :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter a num : 2
Result : 2
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter a num : 12
Result : 4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter a num : 44
Result : 4
```

but the result can be anything else

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile as listed...and not returning from your sum function is causing undefined behavior.  But more to your question, your recursion needs to eventually "bottom out".  There needs to be some scenario in which a "base case" is met and the function returns something other than itself.  For example, try running the below code and see how x changes with different input...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int x);
int main() {
    int num;
    printf("Enter a num : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);
    int result = sum(num);
    printf("Result : %d\n", result);
    return 0;
}

int sum(int x) {
    if (x > 4) {
        printf("x is %d\n", x);
        return sum(x - 1);
    }
    return 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It can be compiled in my ide, i guess it depends on ide. 
http://oi66.tinypic.com/nnp0xw.jpg
So its kinda a bug!

Comment: I'd be careful not to call it a bug.  Undefined behavior is an advanced topic that you should be careful to avoid for now.  Always return from your functions that intend to return a value.

Comment: @HasanMuzak " It can be compiled in my ide, i guess it depends on ide. " - No. That's completely wrong. Just because something *compiles* does *not* mean it is correct. The C++ language allows a *lot* of broken stuff to compile. It just has Undefined Behaviour, meaning you have *no* guarantees about the output. *You* must know the rules of the language and don't break them. If you *do* break them you get random garbage.

Comment: @bitbangs that program is bugged, UB is not an "advanced" topic

Comment: @JesperJuhl oh got it! thanks a lot guys. You helped me and i understand now!